# What is the proper way to implement Server-Side Paging with Kendo UI?

Tags: asp.net-core, kendo-ui, grid, kendo-grid

Similar question to [Kendo ui Paging on grid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39447585/implement-server-side-paging-with-client-side-kendo-ui-grid).  I've got 3,000 items that can be returned into the Grid.  Filtering can reduce that to zero.  I want to be able to page the 3,000 items into the grid and return only the, let's say 50, items that appear on each page (for any given filter).

```
    <div class="col-md-10">
    <div class="clearfix" name="funddetail" id="funddetail" style="display: inline-block">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<InvestmentViewModel>()
                .Name("grid")
                .ToolBar(tools =>
                {
                    tools.Create();
                })
                .HtmlAttributes(new { @class = "k-widget k-grid" })
                .Selectable()
                .Columns(columns =>
                {
                    columns.Bound(c => c.EMSFundId).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.FundId).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.ManagerId).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Status).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.ManagerId).Hidden(true);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.ManagerName).Sortable(true).Title("Entity").Filterable(false);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.FundName).Sortable(true);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.AssetClass).Sortable(true);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.Strategy).Sortable(true);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.SubStrategy).Sortable(true);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.OwnerFullName).Sortable(true);
                    columns.Bound(c => c.StatusDescription).Sortable(true).Filterable(f => f.Cell(c => c.Operator("startswith").SuggestionOperator(FilterType.StartsWith)));

                })
                .Resizable(r => r.Columns(true))
                .Scrollable()
                .Sortable(sortable => sortable
                    .AllowUnsort(false)
                    .SortMode(GridSortMode.SingleColumn))
                .Pageable(pageable => pageable
                    .Refresh(true)
                    .PageSizes(new int[] { 50, 100, 500 })
                    .ButtonCount(10))
                .DataSource(dataSource =>
                    dataSource
                    .WebApi()
                    .PageSize(50)
                    .Model(model =>
                    {
                        model.Id(p => p.FundId);
                    })
                    .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
                    .Read(read => read.Action("GetInvestmentsAsync", "Views"))
                )
        )
    </div>
```

I've set up the Web API to transmit the Page and PageSize to the service.  I can effectively query the data model and return just the page that the Kendo Grid is asking for (e.g. 50 lines from Page 3).  Here's where I'm stuck: the Kendo Grid is showing just one page of 50 elements.  How do I tell the grid there are 3,000 total items and 10 possible pages?

Comment: You can't just return `InvestmentModel`. Kendo expects data to bind converted inro `Kendo.Mvc.UI.DataSourceResult` which has `Data, Total` Properties. You can assign your model to `Data` and set `Total` so that Kendo will create pages on its own. Also, can you please add your method `GetInvestmentsAsync` here?

Comment: OK.  I see the infrastructure now and it looks pretty good.  It looks like the DataSourceRequest and the DataSourceResults need to be serialized in order to be placed in an URI for the request and in JSON for the reply.  Do you have a reference or example of how to Serialize/Deserialize these types?

Answer (score 2):

Your method should look something like this. Please note that It is not a tested code but enough to give you an idea about where you could go wrong.

```
public ActionResult GetInvestmentsAsync([DataSourceRequest] DataSourceRequest request)
{
  DataSourceRequest fakeRequest = new DataSourceRequest()
          {
              Groups = request.Groups,
              Filters = request.Filters,
              Sorts = request.Sorts
          };

    var investments = // fetch your data here, use a viewmodel to hold data and Total records
    DataSourceResult result;
          try
          {
              result = investments.ToDataSourceResult(fakeRequest);
          }
          catch
          {
              result = dataTable.ToDataSourceResult(new DataSourceRequest());
          }

    result.Total = investments.TotalRecords; // Assign Total here
    return JsonResults(result);
}
```

Comment: This looks good, and it's very close to what I worked out on my own.  However, the big difference is that we're talking about communicating to the server through a RESTful API.  So the controller here would issue a **httpClient.GetAsync** and the service would return the **DataSourceResult** as JSON.  However, it doesn't appear that the **DataSourceRequest** or the **DataSourceResult** serialize very well.  Any ideas where I can find help on this?